# Quick conditional loop

Tags: java

Good afternoon guys, i try to resolve this however im stuck on first loop
the original condition i have to do is

```
Consider the following algorithm:
for ( i = 1; i<= 1.5n; i++)
print i
for ( i = n; i >= 1; i--)
print i
(a) What is the output when n = 2, n = 4?
(b) What is the time complexity?
```

and my code looks like this

```
public class HelloWorld1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = (2);


                for (int i=1; i<= 1.5 * n; i++)
                {
                    for ( i = n; i=>1; i--)
                }

{
                System.out.println(i);
```

however i receive error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token ">", delete this token
Syntax error on token ")", EmptyStatement expected after this token

at HelloWorld1.main(HelloWorld1.java:11)
```

I cant seem to figure it out, maybe u can help me out

Comment: It's `<=` and `>=`, not `<=` and `=>`.

Comment: The `basic` tag is for the [BASIC language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC), not for when you have a basic problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i chagned it as u advised and i still got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Syntax error on token ")", EmptyStatement expected after this token

Comment: If you are able, download (for free) eclipse, netbeans or IntelliJ as your java editor.  It will be Very Helpful for this kind of problem!  (I mean, beyond helpful, pretty much invaluable).  They will give you tips when you type wrong code (hover over things that have error indications to see what's wrong and/or see tips on how to fix them.)

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are not placed correctly.

Do it like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<= 1.5 * n; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
    for ( i = n; i>=1; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```